# Rails 4 Strong Parameters in generic controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, strong-parameters

I have a "generic" controller in charge of managing all public pages and actions

```
class PublicController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def contact
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
  end

  private

  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :question, :subject)
  end

end
```

But when I want to access the "contact us" link I have the following error

> param is missing or the value is empty: contact

Is it possible to operate strong parameters inside a "generic" controller or should I only use them as part of a controller named "Contact" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like the error is because you've not got a contact parameter in the parameters hash.  You want something more like the following:

```
def contact
  @contact = Contact.new
end

def send_contact
  @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
end

private

def contact_params
  params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :question, :subject)
end
```

Or

```
def index
  @contact = Contact.new
end

def contact
  @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)   
end

private

def contact_params
  params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :question, :subject)   
end
```

Essentially you should only be calling contact_params on the action you're posting to.

Comment: I actually added a conditional statement to differentiate the state of the action in the controller and took it to work as you explained.